# POSTing data with many to one relationship using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple model class `Product` which exhibits a many to one relationship with `ProductCategory`:

**Product class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="description")
private String description;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="category_id")
private ProductCategory category;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPdfUrl() {
    return pdfUrl;
}

public void setPdfUrl(String pdfUrl) {
    this.pdfUrl = pdfUrl;
}

public ProductCategory getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategoryId(ProductCategory category) {
    this.category = category;
}

}
```

**ProductCategory class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_category",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name")})
public class ProductCategory {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="category")
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);

// getters() & setters()

}
```

I am using Spring boot with Thymeleaf to create the necessary forms for the usual CRUD operations.

Here is the essential portion of my html page which I use to add a new `Product` object into the database.

```
<form action="#" th:action="/product/save" th:object="${newProduct}" method="POST">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
  <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" />
  <select th:field="*{category}">
    <option th:each="category: ${productCategories}" th:value="${category}" th:text="${category.name}" />
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem is, when I try and insert the resulting `Product` object from the controller (I know I haven't shown it here, mostly because I don't think that is actually the cause of the problem), there is a

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'category_id' cannot be null
```

I have tried changing the `value` of the `option` to `${category.id}`, but even that doesn't fix it.

## In a nutshell

How do I actually pass a complex object as a POST parameter into a controller using Thymeleaf?

## Update

Contrary to my first thoughts, this might actually be related to my `Controller`, so here is my `ProductController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newProduct") Product product, ModelMap model) {
    productRepo.save(product);
    model.addAttribute("productCategories", productCategoryRepo.findAll());
    return "admin-home";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/product/save")
public String addProduct(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("newProduct", new Product());
    model.addAttribute("productCategories", productCategoryRepo.findAll());
    return "add-product";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note that I have changed the form method to POST.**

From thymeleafs perspective I can assure the below code should work.

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/product/save}" th:object="${newProduct}">
    ....
    <select th:field="*{category}" class="form-control">
       <option th:each="category: ${productCategories}" th:value="${category.id}" th:text="${category.name}"></option>
    </select>
```

Provided that your controller looks like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/save")
public String create(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("productCategories", productCategoryService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("newproduct", new Product()); //or try to fetch an existing object
    return '<your view path>';
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/product/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("newProduct") Product newProduct, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        //error handling  
        ....
    }else {
        //or calling the repository to save the newProduct
        productService.save(newProduct);
        ....
    }
}
```

**Update**

Your models should have proper getters and setters with the correct names. For example, for the property `category` You should have,

```
public ProductCategory getCategory(){
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(productCategory category){
    this.category = category;
}
```

**NOTE** - *I have not compiled this code, I got it extracted from my current working project and replace the names with your class names*

Comment: I actually left out the `method="post"` when I was editing the actual post. I've updated my question with the controller I have originally created. I'll try out your's , but can you suggest what is actually wrong with mine?

Comment: when you run the form page can you goto the html source view and paste the source which is rendered for the form element along with the input and select elements inside the form element.

Comment: `<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
            <option value="4">Foo</option>
            <option value="2">Bar</option>
            <option value="3">FooBar</option>
            <option value="1">BarFoo</option>
           </select>`

Comment: I tried submitting data as json from the command line using curl, but with no success.

Comment: Try to debug the controller action and see if it's only the category which is not fetched or it's all the fields which are not fetched from the POST? and in your controller file have u set any custom validators?

Comment: Nope. I haven't got any custom validators. And I might take some time getting back to you on this as I'm going out for a holiday for 2 or 3 days from now. I'll updates once I get back. Thank you. :)

Comment: I'm getting a `null` value at the `category` when I debug the controller. Has it got anything to do with the way I mapped the model classes?

Comment: check the posted data from the browser and see if this contains the category or category_id in it along with the other variables. if so the culprit should be in the server.

Comment: Hope you have `public` getters and setters for the `Category` Please recheck that too. The names should be `getCategory` and `setCategory`

Comment: Thank You very much! I had the setter for the `category` wrong! The first time I generated the setter the field was named `categoryId` which I somehow missed while renaming. After changing it everything is fine. I guess it's one of those errors where you need just a different pair of eyes to figure out! Should I close this question then?

Comment: You are welcome. :) I will update my answer so that It will make sense of getters and setters

Comment: Alright. I shall also edit the question so that it shows the faulty setter too. :)