# How to work with the object in Thymeleaf dropdown

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and stuck with a strange issue. Let me tell you what works first. I have two simple class

```
public class Country {

    private long countryid;

    private String name;
}
```

And

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private long countryId;
}
```

In the addPerson page I want to select the country from a dropdown. I have manually created a list of countries ( from spring controller) and then my addPerson.html is designed as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Person</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/addPerson}" th:object="${person}"
        method="POST">
        <p>
            Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
        </p>
        <select th:field="*{countryId}" class="form-control">
            <option th:each="country: ${countryList}"
                th:value="${country.countryid}" th:text="${country.name}"></option>
        </select>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset"
                value="Reset" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I select a country from dropdown, I get the countryid and everything works fine.
Now I want to change my Person class as below

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private Country country;
}
```

So, instead of the countryid, I want to have the country object itself. Keeping everything else same, I have changed my addPerson.html to

```
<select th:field="*{country}" class="form-control">
            <option th:each="country: ${countryList}"
                th:value="${country}" th:text="${country.name}"></option>
</select>
```

Now I can see the dropdown, but upon submitting, I am getting an error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Validation failed for object='person'. Error count: 1

**In short** : It works with property of the object, what I need to do to work with the entire object itself?

Kindly help.

**UPDATE 1:** the controller method signature

```
@GetMapping("/addPerson")
    public String addPerson(Model model) {

        Country country1 = new Country();
        country1.setCountryid(1);
        country1.setName("A");

        Country country2 = new Country();
        country2.setCountryid(2);
        country2.setName("B");

        List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        countryList.add(country1);
        countryList.add(country1);

        model.addAttribute("countryList", countryList);
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        return "addPerson";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addPerson")
    public void processAddPerson(@Valid @ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {

        System.out.println(person.getName());

    }
```

**UPDATE 2**
Upon debugging, I found out that in the second case, on submit, the control is not going to `setCountry` method of Person class at all!

Comment: add controller method signature.

Comment: @Alien: Updated. Kindly check.

Comment: That's just a workaround, but in my option we don't need to use binding in every use-case. Don't use the th:field="*{country}" attribute. Keep it simple and 1.) go with name="countryId", 2.) recieve the countryId as an extra parameter in your processAddPerson-method and 3.) "wire" a country-object to the person-object manually in the method. Binding is create but sometimes it doesn't worth the effort to do it at all costs.

Comment: @Flocke: Hi Flocke, many thanks for your reply. My actual use case is different, which can be found in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571933/loading-and-saving-a-form-field-populated-from-a-second-form-field-using-thymele . I narrowed down the problem in the current post. As you can see there, I really require the selected object. It is really surprising why the setter method is not getting called! If you have any idea please share.

Comment: @user3274247: That's not thymleaf-specific trouble. I know this from spring-binding and jsp and the so called solution is to define your own formatters (that's what you have to do). Your generated option-code looks like <option value="[1, UK]">UK</option>. That's not a Country-object, it's a String. Therefore, you need a Formatter that creates a Country-object from that input ([1, UK]) and is annotated in the Person-class.

Answer (score 0):

Add BindingResult Object to your method.

```
 public String processAddPerson( @Valid Person person,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model)
```

Ensure that the `BindingResult` has to be *immediately* after the object annotated with `@Valid`.

Comment: Hi Alien, thanks for your answer. But in the controller, `country` field is still null. So the dropdown selection didn't work. Could you please help with that ?

Comment: try to put name="person" in thymeleaf select tag and check.

Comment: No success :( I tried with name="country"/id="country" as well, no avail!

Comment: Like mentioned in the main-thread: You need to define a cosumer Formatter.